# getting the Amazon UserID for in app purchase receipt validation with Amazon's Adobe AIR native extension

Tags: actionscript, air, in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

Basically, it's all in the title. I'm trying to validate receipts with Amazon from our server after using the Adobe AIR ANE from Amazon's SDK to handle purchasing. To validate the receipt though I need three things: the developer secret (got it), the purchaseToken (getting that too!), and amazon's app-specific user id (can't freakin figure out how to get it!).

I know for native programming, you use the ongetUserIDResponse event, but there doesn't seem to be any corresponding event using the AIR native extension.

Many thanks in advance!

**Solved**: http://27.251.180.103/php-team/anju/gamer-emporium/SAMPLE%20CODES/Apps-SDK/Android/InAppPurchasing/plugins/adobe/docs/as3doc/com/amazon/nativeextensions/android/AmazonPurchase.html#getCurrentUser()

AmazonPurchase.amazonPurchase.getCurrentUser() returns the amazon user id.

Comment: Finally figured it out: AmazonPurchase.amazonPurchase.getCurrentUser(). This is of course completely undocumented by Amazon as far as I can tell. I found it here: http://27.251.180.103/php-team/anju/gamer-emporium/SAMPLE%20CODES/Apps-SDK/Android/InAppPurchasing/plugins/adobe/docs/as3doc/com/amazon/nativeextensions/android/AmazonPurchase.html#getCurrentUser()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved: http://27.251.180.103/php-team/anju/gamer-emporium/SAMPLE%20CODES/Apps-SDK/Android/InAppPurchasing/plugins/adobe/docs/as3doc/com/amazon/nativeextensions/android/AmazonPurchase.html#getCurrentUser()

AmazonPurchase.amazonPurchase.getCurrentUser() returns the amazon user id.